# Use bar3 instead of bar to plot multiple data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have 3 matrices `A`, `B` and `C` where each of them is of size `21x2`. I use `bar` to plot each one separately. I'm wondering how I can plot the three together using `bar3`?

So using this code:

```
A=rand(21,2);
B=rand(21,2);
C=rand(21,2);
fig=figure();b1=bar(A);
fig2=figure();b2=bar(B);
fig3=figure();b3=bar(C);
```

will generate these three figures:

A:

[image]

B:

[image]

C:

[image]

And what I want to do is that I want them to be all the the same figure but plotted behind each other in the z direction to be something like [this](http://www.google.com.au/imgres?imgurl=http://148.204.81.206/matlab/ref/bar3_detached.png&imgrefurl=http://148.204.81.206/matlab/ref/bar3.html&h=576&w=768&tbnid=7ca107ksUACwOM:&zoom=1&docid=FTBgcFTVk4-zGM&ei=sgg6VYyrOsHNmwW1wYHQCw&tbm=isch&client=ubuntu-browser&ved=0CCMQMygHMAc)

Comment: What have you tried? This looks as easy as `bar3(x,y)` so I am assuming you have a problem somewhere else. Maybe the values of the data? Show us a MCVE.

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks for your comment. What are `x` and `y`? I just have a 3 matrices of size `21x2` which I would normally plot them separately using `bar`. But now I don't know how to plot them separately but still in the same graph if you understand what I mean.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve <- MCVE . Shows us some example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to create new variables that contain all the data you want in each row intercalated with NaNs. Just that change gives you almost the solution.

```
for ii=1:size(A,1)
   A1((ii-1)*3+1)=A(ii,1);
   A1((ii-1)*3+2)=A(ii,2);
   A1((ii-1)*3+3)=NaN;

   B1((ii-1)*3+1)=B(ii,1);
   B1((ii-1)*3+2)=B(ii,2);
   B1((ii-1)*3+3)=NaN;

   C1((ii-1)*3+1)=C(ii,1);
   C1((ii-1)*3+2)=C(ii,2);
   C1((ii-1)*3+3)=NaN;
end

h=bar3(horzcat(A1',B1',C1'))
```

However, I am guessing that you also want to modify the colors.
To do this, the idea is that you can get the colour data for each bar row using `get(h(nrow),'Cdata')`.

with this trick and your own colormap you should be able to colour the bars independently. It is not straightforward, but where's the fun if its easy!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've updated my question with examples and screenshots to show what I want to do, so if you could please have a look.

Comment: @shepherd So you have 6 data separated in 3 matries? That is confusing! Anyway, to be able to plot all of the 6 then do `bar3(horzcat(A,B,C))`

Comment: But this is not what I want. See in my screenshots how each of A, B and C has 21x 2bars(sticked together)? I want the same thing (not separated) but for the three of them. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @shepherd Aaahhh! thats Why a MCVE is needed! That explanation was completely absent before. Let me edit my question, if possible.

Comment: please let me know when you update your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: but this is not the result I'm looking for as well. This is how it is appearing http://i.imgur.com/BWSnovt.png?1

Comment: @shepherd Yes, I know.  They are "all the the same figure but plotted behind each other". Can you show an image of what you want? If we co one by one taking out the things you dont want it will take ages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76154/discussion-between-shepherd-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: @shepherd I'm pretty sure I showed you how to create `bar3` in your previous question